# Connection via SQuirreL works but via own app doesn't. Receive access denied for user

Tags: java, mysql

sorry for my broken english, not a native speaker :)

Here is my problem:
I try to connect via JDBC to a DB hosted on a MySQL server (Version: 5.6.37). I don't host the server and can't change any server configs.
When I try to connect using SQuirreL everything works as expected. I get access to the DB.
When I try to connect via self-written app via my IDE (eclipse) I get an Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ... (using password: YES)

I'm using HikariCP to manage the connections. Tried also non connection pool aproach via DriverManager.getConnection. Both times the same.

The driver I'm using is mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar

```
// DriverManager approach
private static final Properties dbProps = new Properties();
static {
    dbProps.put("password", dbPass);
    dbProps.put("user", dbUser);
    dbProps.put("autoReconnect", "true");
    dbProps.put("failOverReadOnly", "false");
    dbProps.put("maxReconnects", "1");
}

...
public static Connection getConnection() {
    Connection con = null;
    try {
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, dbProps);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return con;
}
...
// HakiriCP approach
private static HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
private static HikariDataSource ds;
private static final Properties dbProps = new Properties();
static {
    PropertyLoader.loadPropertiesFromFile(dbProps); // read properties from external source

    config.setJdbcUrl(String.format("jdbc:mysql://%s:%s/%s", dbProps.getProperty("db.server"),
        dbProps.getProperty("db.port"), dbProps.getProperty("db.database")));
    config.setUsername(dbProps.getProperty("db.user"));
    config.setPassword(dbProps.getProperty("db.pass"));
    config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", dbProps.getProperty("db.cachePrepStmts", "true"));
    config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", dbProps.getProperty("db.prepStmtCacheSize", "250"));
    config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", dbProps.getProperty("db.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048"));
    ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
}

...

public static Connection getConnection() {
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        con = ds.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return con;
}
...
```

**EDIT** - when I wireshark the connection tries, I see different encoded passwords (SQuirreL vs App). But when I print the password to the console it is exactly the one that work with SQuirreL.

**EDIT** - The connecttion handling is done in one single class. When I test it all alone without any of the other logic (it is a old swing app) everything works fine. But when I make the exact same call from the swing application it fails '(sends different password string).
What am I doing wrong?

I'm thankful for every help.

Cheers!

Comment: Please show your code (where you connect to the database using `DriverManager.getConnection()`

Comment: Seems the values you gave SQuirreL is somehow different from the values you gave your Java code. Did you remember to escape special characters, e.g. use ``\\``?

Comment: @Andreas: copy&paste the values from SQuirreL into the java code. No, I didn't escape any characters. I read the values from a propeties file.

Comment: Try printing the values to ensure they got loaded correctly.

Comment: @Andreas: when I print all the values they look exactly the same (as they are stored in the properties file and used in SQuirreL)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. For all the project I have UTF-8 encoding. But eclipse decided to use UTF-16 when running or debugging code.
Option can be found here: Run Configurations -> Common -> Encoding

Ok, eclipse made some joke with me. 
Thanks to wireshark givin me the hint that something is wrong with the encoding.

Thanks to you guys to trying to help (inluding the ones giving me -1, they don't know it better ;))

Cheers!